# web part not shown in sharepoint team site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have a simple project where I am creating a label in Visual Studio 2012 and wrote in the page load function `label.text="welcome to sharpoint team site"`.

When the site opened, I didn't find the label text.  I tried to debug, but I don't know where the problem is.

*Note : When I created the project, I chose farm not sandbox.*

Answer (score 0):

My first Question is :

Do you deployed your solution ? Make Sure that the feature is activated on the site or site collection

Did you drop your web part on the page where you are looking ?

Try to Put the webpart again on the page and see the result,